# Convert GMS to HMS using HMS Toolkit

Tags: android, firebase, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

Good Day!

I have an app publish on Google Play Store but I want to publish it into AppGallery, I`ve just converted my codes using HMS Toolkit. But I am a little bit confused on this hope everyone can answer my questions below:

1. After Conversion I can upload the app on AppGallery and all functions of my App on Playstore will still work also on HMS? Like the Start iO adds
2. Do i need to delete the google-services.json and replace it with agconnect-services.json? Because I am using One Signal push notification and it is using firebase.

Please check also the error when I am trying to sync the project after the conversion:
[image]

Sorry for my bad english I am not good on explaining things.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you select the **G+H approach** when using the Convoror conversion. The bridged XMS API enables your application to call both GMS and HMS APIs.

On devices that support HMS APIs but do not support GMS APIs, your app calls HMS APIs. And on devices that support both HMS APIs and GMS APIs, apps can determine whether to call GMS APIs or HMS APIs preferentially based on your settings.

For details about GMS *Add HMS API Policy*, you could refer to this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/appendix-0000001050061063#section463485816495).

Comment: ok I’ll choose this later, but what does the errors mean on the screenshot?

Comment: hi maam @shirley do you have any idea how to resolve this issue? A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':xmsadapter'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: hi@Clinton Canarias, sorry for the late reply, After the covertor is used, the xmsadapter module is generated. But seems the xmsadapter module is not displayed in the screenshot. So pls check whether the xmsadapter module is generated properly. You could follow this [Convertor usage guide Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/convertor-0000001050147221).

Comment: please feel free to contact me if you need any further help. :)

Comment: Hi @shirly how about the json file? I will use both google-services.json and agconnect-services.json or I will replace the google-services.json?

Comment: hi@Clinton Canarias, If you use G+H policy, you need both google-service.json and agcconnect-service.json.  Acctually, you need not to modify any project configuration files after converted.

Comment: ok maam I keep both files, only the xmsadapter issue I couldn’t resolved I followed the step on your documention but still same error. Do you have other documention regarding to xmsadapter issue?

Comment: hi@Clinton Canarias, While converting your 'G' project to 'G+H' project , Convortor will automatically create xmsadapter module, which contains XMS APIs that enables your application to call both GMS and HMS APIs. Your error screen shot shows there exists errors in the generation of xmsadpater module. So I hope you can check use guide of Convortor to make sure you have done a correct convertion.

Comment: Currently, Chinese engineers are in their national day holidays. If the use guide can not help you, please provide the build.gradle(both project level and module level) in your project. I will ask our R&D team give you a quick responese after they are back.

Comment: I didn’t know why I always got an error converting my codes. but I submitted my apps already I just added HMS waiting it for approval

Comment: hi@Clinton Canarias, sorry for the late reply, Our team engineers want to arrange a video conference with you to tarce your problem. may i ask what is your country? And when is it convenient to video conferencing? It would be nice if you could leave your email address then we can send you the meeting link.